# Strange UICollectionView behaviour when VoiceOver is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that each of it's cells is a `UIWebView`, where the last cell contains a link that pushes another `UIViewController` on screen. This `UIViewController` has a back button that pops the `UIViewController` off screen and should display the last cell on the `UICollectionView` again.

This flow works fine when VoiceOver is turned off, however when VoiceOver is turned on, when the user taps on the back button - the collection view automatically scrolls back to the first cell.

I've googled this to death, but nothing seems to work.
Any suggestions?